# Matriz dá sempre o mesmo resultado quando tento armazena-lá em uma Lista em R

Tags: r, matriz

Estou tentando escrever um código que guarda resultados da rolagem de dados em cada linha de uma matriz e armazena matrizes dentro de uma lista, o código funciona mas quando peço para ver a lista de Matrizes os resultados das rolagens são iguais e eu queria um resultado aleatório em cada lista.

```
matriz <-matrix(1:5, nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
listas <- list()

rolar <- function() {
  dados <- 1:6
  dados <- replicate(1, sample(dados, size = 1, replace = TRUE))
  return(dados)
}

for (i in 1:10) {
  matriz[i,] <- rolar()
  listas[[i]] <- matriz
  print(listas[i])
}

str(listas)
```

Answer (score 4):

As matrizes não são iguais; cada uma corresponde à anterior com uma linha consecutiva modificada. Eis uma versão mais simples do que está fazendo para ficar mais claro:

```
set.seed(79)

matriz <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
lista <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
  matriz[i,] <- sample(1:6, 1)
  lista[[i]] <- matriz
}

lista
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    6    6    6    6    6
#> [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#>
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    6    6    6    6    6
#> [2,]    3    3    3    3    3
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#>
#> [[3]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    6    6    6    6    6
#> [2,]    3    3    3    3    3
#> [3,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

O que o código está fazendo:

Sua função:

- cria um vetor com os números de 1 a 6
- sorteia um valor entre 1 e 6 (note que `replicate(1, ...` e `sample(..., size = 1` resultam em *um* valor)
- sobrescreve o vetor `dados` com o valor sorteado

Seu *loop*:

- 1a volta: substitui os valores da 1a linha da matriz por um valor de 1 a 6 (o mesmo valor é replicado em todas as colunas); grava a matriz atualizada no primeiro elemento da lista
- 2a volta: sorteia outro valor, coloca na segunda linha e grava a matriz no segundo elemento da lista
- etc

Não ficou claro o resultado final que deseja. Se é uma lista com 10 matrizes 10x5 com sorteios aleatórios:

```
lapply(1:10, function(x) matrix(sample(1:6, 10*5, TRUE), nrow = 10, ncol = 5))
```

Comment: é isso mesmo o resultado final esperado! 10 matrizes com elementos aleatórios, de 1 a 6, matrizes de 10 linhas e cinco colunas

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma função para gerar uma matriz e depois chame a função as vezes que forem precisas.

```
#
# função para gerar uma matriz aleatória
# argumentos:
#   n - números de 1 a n
#   nrow, ncol - dimensões da matriz
#
rolar <- function(n = 6, nrow = 10, ncol = 5) {
  matrix(sample(n, nrow*ncol, TRUE), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)
}

# chamar 10 vezes a função cria um array 3d de 10 matrizes
set.seed(2022)
r1 <- replicate(10, rolar())

# mas com 'simplify = FALSE' o resultado é uma lista de 10 matrizes
set.seed(2022)
r2 <- replicate(10, rolar(), simplify = FALSE)
```

Para aceder aos resultados:

```
r1[, , 1]    # primeira matriz
r2[[1]]      # primeira matriz

identical(r1[, , 1], r2[[1]])
#[1] TRUE
```